# In Dash subplots how do I only increase the height of the very first plot keeping other subplots unchanged?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Because, the `height` of all the `subplots` are same. I just want to increase the `height` of my `first subplot` only.

```
fig['layout'].update(height=700, width=1300, title='TITLE')
```

The above code gives me the total `height` and `width`. But I just want to increase the height of my first subplot plot and leave the other subplots unchanged when we are using `Stacked subplots`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `specs` and set the rowspan of the first plot larger than the other plots

> The specs argument to make_subplots is used to configure per-subplot options. specs must be a 2-dimension list with dimensions that match those provided as the rows and cols arguments.

https://plotly.com/python/subplots/

Example:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=4,
    cols=1,
    specs=[[{"rowspan": 2}], [{}], [{}], [{}]],
)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]), row=3, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]), row=4, col=1)
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600)

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You also should be able to do this with the `row_heights` argument.

```
make_subplots(
    ...,
    row_heights=[2, 1, 1],
    ...,
)
```